# Android Compare EditText value with current date

Tags: android

i have been trying to check if date from an edit text field in my android app is > than current date before moving to a new intent but i couldn't reach any solution

hopefully someone can advise , kindly

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried so far, please?

Comment: post some code, maybe we can help

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

**or**

```
   LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); 
int year = now.getYear();
int month = now.getMonthValue();
int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
int hour = now.getHour();
 int minute = now.getMinute();
 int second = now.getSecond();
```

Comment: Android doesn't have Java 8 LocalDateTime

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend looking at JodaTime (in jdk 8 you should use the java.time package).  Specifically check out http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial.html#isAfter(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial) which is a parent class of `LocalDate` which you can use.

See `LocalDate#now` and `LocalDate#parse` for building instances of these classes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the date format will be in the `EditText` you'll want to get that data and create an instance of `Date` so you can compare the two.

Example:

```
String rawDate = EditText.getText().toString();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("expected format", Locale.US); 
Date inputDate = format.parse(rawDate);
Date currentDate = new Date();
if(inputDate.after(currentDate)){
//if editText date is after
else{
//if editText date is not after
}
```

Note: `Date` is not the best option when it comes to date and time in Java. As other people suggested, Joda is a very good alternative. I recommend you read the documentation and other articles on the subject so you know what taking Joda in your project would mean and if you actually need it or not.

Comment: though not recommended , yet this option worked for me , i read the JOda documentation but i couldn't use . I don't believe i need Joda for the current time , as my concern is to make sure to make sure edit text value doesn't exceed current date
thank you guys appreciate the help

Comment: You're welcome and I'm happy I could help. Happy coding !